# Calculating time difference in Java with SimpleDateFormat returns 13:15 hr instead of 1:15 hr. eg(end time 13:16 and start time 12:01)

Tags: java, algorithm, calculator, simpledateformat

```
private double calculateAverageSpeed() {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

    try {
        double totalTime;
        totalTime = (format.parse(stopTime + ":00").getTime()) - (format.parse(startTime + ":00").getTime());
        return (milesDriven / totalTime);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you share the format , how you are passing the date to this method

Comment: Trip one 12:01 13:16 42.0
Trip two 07:15 07:45 17.3
Trip three 06:12 06:32 21.8

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

You're parsing strings that look like 24-hour-clock times with a format specifier that wants 12-hour times with AM/PM indicators (hh:mm:ss).

My guess is that "12:01" is interpreted as one minute after midnight.  Use HH:mm:ss for 24-hour times.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help you
Also you can use time format "HH:mm" for 24 hour format , I have used "hh:mm"

if you use "HH:mm"

you will get result like this

Time: Thu Jan 01 12:01:00 PST 1970 72060000 
Time: Thu Jan 01 13:16:00 PST 1970 76560000 
diff==4500000 
totalTime=1 
42.0

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class TimeDifference {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

  System.out.println(calculateAverageSpeed("12:01","13:16",42.0));
 

}

 private static double calculateAverageSpeed(String time1,String time2, double 
 miles) throws ParseException { 

DecimalFormat decimalFormatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###");
 

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = format.parse(time1);
Date date2 = format.parse(time2);

System.out.println("Time: " + date+ " "+date.getTime());
System.out.println("Time: " + date2+ " "+date2.getTime());
long diff = date2.getTime() - date.getTime();
System.out.println("diff=="+diff); 
int totalTime = (int)(diff/(60*60*1000));
System.out.println("totalTime="+decimalFormatter.format(totalTime));

return  (miles / totalTime);
}


}
```

you will get kind of this result .
Time: Thu Jan 01 00:01:00 PST 1970 28860000 
Time: Thu Jan 01 13:16:00 PST 1970 76560000 
diff==47700000 
totalTime=13 
3.230769230769231

Comment: Total still comes to 13 with this solution, should be 1hr

Comment: yeah for one hour change the format to "HH:mm"